# How to slow my internet connection down so that I can test what my site looks like on a slower connection?

Tags: performance, testing

My area recently got 4g internet and it has sped things up to much. Yes, you read right, I want to be able to slow down my browser so that I can watch websites loading. Both for testing my own site so that I can see what other people with slower connections see. Plus I have found that with a lot of sites what I want to see is at the top, so with a slower connection when what I want to see has loaded I can stop downloading the rest of the site and save some of my bandwidth for other things.

Is there a program, or add-on for Firefox that would allow me to do such a thing? If I have to I could limit the connection its self. I am on a window 7 machine with Verizon mobile broadband that plugs into a flash drive.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/135719/windows-program-to-limit-bandwidth-of-other-programs

Answer (score 7):

You can use chrome to simulate internet speed directly.

See this: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network-performance/network-conditions

Answer (score 6):

You can use Fiddler and it's feature Simulate modem speed.

Main menu -> Rules -> Performance -> Simulate Modem Speeds

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here is what I found in:
http://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/proxying/throttling/

"Charles can be used to adjust the bandwidth and latency of your Internet connection. This enables you to simulate modem conditions using your high-speed connection.

The bandwidth may be throttled to any arbitrary bytes per second. This enables any connection speed to be simulated.

The latency may also be set to any arbitrary number of milliseconds. The latency delay simulates the latency experienced on slower connections, that is the delay between making a request and the request being received at the other end"

Answer (score 2):

There are couple of tools in the market which can throttle your network speed both uplink and downlink. http://bandwidthcontroller.com/trafficShaperXp.html is one such tool. There are couple of others as well. We generally do it via shunra emulator.